# LyX error - the document could not be saved

Tags: errors, lyx

I have just installed LyX on my Laptop.

I tried to edit an existing .lyx document I had and then I tried to save it.
I am getting the following error: "The document could not be saved. Do you want to rename the document and try again?"

[image]

When trying to rename and save in the same location I get the following error:

[image]

More information:

1. I'm running windows 10
2. I tried to run LyX as administrator but those errors stay the same.
   The UAC is set as low as possible, and I am logged on as the administrator.
3. The file is also not read-only.
4. The file is in a local folder within Dropbox, which may be related to the issue. I tried exiting dropbox process but I still get the same error, clicking "Retry" also gets this error.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did saving with a new name help? Perhaps the file was write-protected somehow.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. - I added that information, this seems to be some permissions problems

Comment: Can you save some other file in this location, e.g. a normal text file?

Comment: Sometimes, Windows locks a document or directory because it is used or modified by another program. The reason is not always obvious. If so, a reboot will help.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer - yes, I can edit and save text files within that folder.

Comment: @user24582 - a restart didn't help

Comment: Then something blocks probably specifically .lyx files. Check if some firewall or virus protection / defender is active and overeager. Check also the content of the pathext environment variable. Check your dropbox settings. And don't run lyx as admin but with your normal user rights:  admins often don't have the rights to write into user folders.

Comment: I've seen Windows users have this error occasionally and I've never been able to reproduce on Ubuntu. If you find the problem, please let us know. Note that LyX 2.3.0rc1 should be out soon. You could give that a try if you were very daring (but of course you should back everything up before a big change).

Comment: Do you see the problem if you disable Dropbox? I wonder if this is related in some way to http://www.lyx.org/trac/ticket/10091

Comment: Same problem. Also use Dropbox. Could be Dropbox. I just click "retry" and it works.

Comment: @YikaiWang - retry doesn't work for me. I added this detail to the post

Comment: Since this is not really a (La)TeX problem but rather one with permissions, it could be useful to ask it on [Super User](https://superuser.com/). There may be people able to help you there.

Comment: Maybe if you can you start Lyx from the command line with: `lyx -dbg files`, the output helps...

Comment: @UlrikeFischer nailed it, for me it was my antivirus software blocking write access of lyx.exe to the Desktop folder. Problem was resolved after allowing lyx.exe to write to system folders (such as Documents and Desktop).

Comment: I've noticed this as well on Windows (but not Ubuntu), and it does seem to be Dropbox related. If you just pause the syncing while saving these errors never occur, and then resume syncing when done. Frustrating.

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem, I think it is caused by the way dropbox manages files on windows.

Lyx creates a new file and then tries to change its name, which under dropbox creates a conflict which cannot be resolved automatically.

I suggest working outside the dropbox folder and only move the finished files there.

Answer (score 2):

For me, it helped a bit to switch of the "backup original document when saving" in LyX Tools->Settings. In LyX Version 2.3.4.3.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As of Windows 10 (1803), the issue may also be caused by Windows Defender's optional ransomware protection, which doesn't recognize LyX as a legitimate program by default.

Note that nothing will indicate, that this feature is the cause.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. Strangely, this works in 95% of the time: you get the error message "The document could not be saved..." when you click on Save, so just hit ESC (i.e. don't save it under a different name), and then press Save again (i.e. under the same name) - and Lyx saves it! In the 5% of the cases it doesn't work, just do it again: ESC, Save etc... It always works eventually.

So what Lyx protests against, Lyx does do 2 seconds(!) later. A mystery... People say it must be Dropbox: but I do save other types of files into Dropbox and I only encounter with this problem in Lyx.

Answer (score 0):

Bit of an old thread but we have just resolved this very same error on a new PC install by assigning the remote drive holding the file to a letter (mapped the file location to Z drive in our instance).
Once the file is accessed via the new path which now includes the mapped drive letter all works fine.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!